# How do I copy stopword folder from my local machine to a folder in ubuntu with restricted access (in Termius)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nltk

I am really a beginner in Ubuntu. I wanted to deploy my web application (which is made on an AWS EC2 instance, Ubuntu 20.04). This web application has dependencies such as nltk, which needs stopwords data. This is what made me unable to deploy my web application to AWS, because the machine could not find the stopwords data in some certain directories (I remember them being lib, root, etc)

To connect to the Ubuntu instance, I used Termius, because it enables me to move files from my own machine to the Ubuntu instance. However, given that the folder in which I wanted to move my stopwords data to has restricted access, is there a way in which I can move my stopwords data to that folder? Or is there a way to redirect the machine to a new folder that has no restricted access?

I will be glad if anyone can help me, thank you very much!

Comment: I recommend asking on: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: do you have control over the ubuntu machine? maybe you could just change permissions on the applicable folders